# How can I traverse all the children of all tags to get the data using lxml in python?

Tags: python, lxml

I want to traverse all the child nodes in html page. 
e.g  `<body>......</body>` will have many child tags I want to traverse all those tags recursively so that none of the tag remains unvisited. Then I want to get the text from each tag. 
I am looking for a general solution which will work for any webpage with any kind of structure it may has. Can anybody suggest this? 
Thank you

Comment: e.g 1) <body>//some text<div><p>//some text<li>//some text</li></p>//Text for End of div</div>//some text</body>

Answer (score 0):

yes , [python beautiful soap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4)
is a great python library with many features to do that.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for solution in using lxml